# Passing a list of values to sql procedure in JPA Repository

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to pass a List/Set of ids to a SQL stored procedure on SQL Server 2012.

I have declared my own table-type but I can't make it feasible to work together with Spring JPA repository which is trying to pass every list element as separate parameter.

This is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentSummaryRepository extends JpaRepository <DocumentSummary, Long> {
    @Query(value = "{call manageDuplicates(:ids)}", nativeQuery = true)
    @Modifying
    int executeProcedure(@Param("ids") Set<Long> ids);
}
```

This is my procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.IDList
AS TABLE
(
  ID INT
);
GO

  CREATE PROCEDURE manageDuplicates @ids AS IDList READONLY
  AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ID FROM @ids; 
END
```

Console log for list with two elements:

```
DEBUG o.h.SQL - {call manageDuplicates(?, ?)}
WARN  o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 8144, SQLState: S0002
ERROR o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - Procedure or function manageDuplicates has too many arguments specified.
```

Log with `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE` as asked for by @Mansoor:

```
DEBUG o.h.SQL - {call manageDuplicates(?, ?)} TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [126] TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [127]
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Can you print what values are being bound by enabling trace level as `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE`

Comment: DEBUG o.h.SQL - {call manageDuplicates(?, ?)}
TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [126]
TRACE o.h.t.d.s.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [127]

Comment: If providing additional information, please edit your question so that it is easier to see for later visitors. It's also often a good idea do mention the person asking for that information like so: @Mansoor This will trigger a notification for them so that they can look at your edit.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?